# How to get data on polymorphisms of TP53 (specifically on codon 72) in TCGA

Tags: database, polymorphism, bioinformatics, mutation

I would like to know if there is any possibility to get polymorphism data of codon 72 of TP53 for different cancers in TCGA.

Using TCGAbiolinks I could retrieve the "Simple Nucleotide Variation" data, for example using:

```
data.category = "Simple Nucleotide Variation",
data.type = "Masked Somatic Mutation",
access = "open")
GDCdownload(query)
maf <- GDCprepare(query)
```

.....but the missense mutations I can see in the maf output file do not contain codon 72 polymorphism (in most of the TCGA cancer datasets) . Also in cbioportal I can't see any mutation in codon 72 in TP53 in different cancer cohorts. Maybe I misunderstand it but I guess the different TCGA datasets haven't been profiled or annotated for non-pathogenic polymorphisms?

All suggestions and thoughts are highly appreciated.

Thanks